# filling a n*n matrix with n elements

Tags: python

I want to fill a nxn matrix with n elements, such that each row and each column has exactly 1 element. E.g. a 3x3 matrix can have following as possible solutions:

```
1 0 0        0 1 0     0 0 1
0 1 0        1 0 0     1 0 0
0 0 1        0 0 1     0 1 0
```

Following is the code i wrote:

```
arr=[[0 for x in xrange(n)] for x in xrange(n)]
i=0
while i<n:
    j=0
    while j<n:
        arr[i][j]=0
        j+=1
    i+=1

i=0
while i<n:
    j=0
    while j<n:
        x=0
        while x<n:
            if((arr[i][x-1]==1) or (arr[x-1][j]==1)):
                break
            x+=1
        if(x==n-1 and arr[i][n-1]==0 and arr[n-1][j]==0):
            arr[i][j]=1
        j+=1
     i+=1
```

But all the elements are stiil 0. Could someone please point out my mistake.

Comment: Please give a sample of the matrix you want.

Comment: @zhangyangyu : i have updated the question with examples

Comment: Do you need to compute more than one possible solution, or is the diagonal matrix sufficient?

Comment: @MarkThomas: more than one.

Comment: How many? The set of all possible solutions would be quite large, especially for large values of n.

Comment: Do you need all matricies? or random one?

Comment: @MarkThomas: True, but I first tried to generate one possible solution using the above code. But it doesn't work. I can generate the rest in the next step

Comment: @RiaD : i want all matrices but i first tried to generate a random one using the above code

Comment: @RiaD i have used arr[ i ][ j ]=1 under the second "if" statement

Comment: if you change `x == n - 1` to `x == n` it will do something (identity matrix?)

Comment: by the way consider using `for i in range(n)` when possible. It's much clearer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Concerning *your* code:

```
arr=[[0 for x in xrange(n)] for x in xrange(n)]
```

The following loop is redundant since the matrix is already initialized to 0:

```
i=0
while i<n:
    j=0
    while j<n:
        arr[i][j]=0
        j+=1
    i+=1
```

Some changes inline now:

```
i=0
while i<n:
    j=0
    while j<n:
        ok = True
        x=0
        while x<n:
            # Why 'x-1' here?
            if((arr[i][x]==1) or (arr[x][j]==1)):
                ok = False
                break
            x+=1
        if ok:
            arr[i][j]=1
        j+=1
    i+=1
```

Answer (score 8):

> n*n matrix with n elements, such that each row and each column has exactly 1 element.

I assume you want a n*n matrix having exactly one *non 0* element on each row/column

---

Are you looking for a way to build a diagonal matrix?

```
>>> n = 5
>>> [[1 if j == i else 0 for j in range(n)] for i in range(n)]
[[1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]]
```

---

If you need *all* possible permutations, you could write:

```
>>> n = 5
>>> m = [[1 if j == i else 0 for j in range(n)] for i in range(n)]
>>> from itertools import permutations
>>> for p in permutations(m):
>>>     print p
```

Comment: diagonal matrix would be only one possible solution, i have updated my question with examples

Comment: @nish All matrix corresponding to your description are permutations of the identity matrix. So, I've updated my answer to show you how to use [itertools.permutations](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) to generate all possible permutations of that matrix.

Comment: Quite an elegant solution. Thanks for the answer. But i wanna figure out what is wrong with my logic

Comment: FYI `range(0,n)` can just be `range(n)`

Comment: @arshajii I don't even know why I have written that way. Fixed now

Answer (score 2):

You may generate all matricies this way:

```
for per in itertools.permutations(range(n)):
  matrix = [[0 for x in xrange(n)] for x in xrange(n)]
  for i, j in enumerate(per):
    matrix[i][j] = 1
  print matrix
```